# Trying to create a new php project

Tags: php, packagist

Trying to create a new php project(for the first time) but there is an error. I have installed composer, php and mysql

C:\Windows\system32> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectbridge

> > 

Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./projectbridge"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)

- Downloading laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)
- Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6): Extracting archive
  Created project in C:\Windows\system32\projectbridge

> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/dflydev/dot-access-data.json: Failed to connect to repo.packagist.org port 443 after 8508 ms: Timed out), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

In CurlDownloader.php line 372:

curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/dflydev/dot-access-data.json: Failed to connect to re
po.packagist.org port 443 after 8508 ms: Timed out

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [ [ []]]

Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong
I have tried to search about it on the internet but have not found the solution.

Comment: Please post text, not pictures.

Comment: 'failed to connect... timed out'  is a network issue. Either on your end, packagist's end (though their [status page](https://status.packagist.org/) says they're up), or in between

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32` why do you create your projects there ?

Comment: @Kazz thanks for the reply mate! I figured it out there was some problem in .ini file and also the path where I was trying to create the project.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Packagist irself? To me, the error message looks like an networking issue